# Setting a pattern with a loop

Tags: for-loop

Ok, Trying to Draw an American flag

I just did the overall thing manually, but not wanting to manually enter points for each individual star, i wanted to use a loop to set them row by row

There are probably easier ways of doing this, but my idea was to use a for-loop, using the control variable as teh additive to place each star (so when loop control increments by 5, first start is placed, then second is placed 5 points away, then by 10 til the row has 6 stars)

By my logic, i have no problems, the IDE has no errors and it complies successfully...........Except the Stars do not show up. At all.

before i implemented the for-loop, the 1 star i had showed up. with it, none do. not even the 1 star

there doesn't appear to be any error yet it isn't working, so is my Idea just fundamentally wrong or what?

The bit that matters:

```
    double StarX[] = {13.0, 15.0, 21.0, 16.0, 18.0, 13.0, 8.0, 11.0, 5.0, 11.0};
    double StarY[] = {50.0, 57.0, 57.0, 61.0, 68.0, 64.0, 68.0, 61.0, 57.0, 57.0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i = i + 5) {
    Polygon Star = new Polygon();
    Star.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
    StarX[0] + i, StarY[0] + i,
    StarX[1] + i, StarY[1] + i,
    StarX[2] + i, StarY[2] + i,
    StarX[3] + i, StarY[3] + i,
    StarX[4] + i, StarY[4] + i,
    StarX[5] + i, StarY[5] + i,
    StarX[6] + i, StarY[6] + i,
    StarX[7] + i, StarY[7] + i,
    StarX[8] + i, StarY[8] + i,
    StarX[9] + i, StarY[9] + i,          
    });

    Star.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    pane.getChildren().add(Star);

}
```

Comment: You don't actually *use* `i` anywhere, so every `Star` you create is the same.

Comment: right i didn't finish that before testing it to see if it worked as it was or not

Even then though, at least 1 star should have shown up, but none do

Comment: What did the code look like when it did draw a single Star?  What happens if you have the loop do 1 iteration?  And what are `S1` and `S2`?

Comment: when it worked, there was no loop. When i added the loop. it failed entirely. There was never any error and it complied right. just no stars showing up

The S1 and S2. are the first and second stripe on the flag. this isn't the whole code and i just drew those in manually. shouldn't really be there

Comment: And when the loop does exactly 1 iteration?

Comment: still nothing. It doesn't seem to matter how many iterations, it just fails when the loop is involved at all.

Comment: And your claim is, if you were to comment out the for line and the closing brace, it would draw a single Star, because nothing else changed?

Comment: sry i failed to get back to this sooner. 
Without the for-loop in place, 1 stars appear, as it should as nothing is looping them.
with the for-loop in place and no other code changed whatsoever, no stars appear, no matter how many iterations go through.